# can lisp implement such a sugar syntax in lisp?

Tags: lisp, common-lisp, syntactic-sugar

Is it possible to implement the following syntax in lisp?

```
#1 + 1 &
=>
(+ #1 1)

#1 + #2 &
=>
(+ #1 #2)
```

"#+(number)" means the n-th argument for function.
"&" means end of function.

Comment: you are aware that Lisp usually does not use infix syntax? But sure, one can implement the input syntax.

Comment: See http://quickdocs.org/fn/, but it is not solely based on reader macros

Comment: See some libraries for lambda shorthands: https://github.com/CodyReichert/awesome-cl#lambda-shorthands

Comment: @RainerJoswig thanks,I just fixed my question's code. I just wanted to know if this is possible,It's enough.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. It can be implemented as a reader macro, but you should know `(lambda x: x + 1)` and `(lambda x, y: x + y)` does not make any sense in lisp. It looks like python syntax with parentheses.

Now reader macros are the stuff that turns `'(3)` into `(quote (3))` and `` `(a b ,(+ a b))` into `(quasiquote (a b (unquote (+ a b))))`

Comment: the actual representation of quasiquote expressions is undefined and differs across implementations...